# Getting Error while generating signed bundle apk---

Tags: android, gradle

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.icgvideocall.react:icgvideocall-meet-sdk:3.10.2.
> Required by:
> project :app

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at

Comment: my build.gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549203/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-app-debug-runtime-classpa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app debug Runtime Classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549203/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-app-debug-runtime-classpa)